# Positioning a Jpanel into another Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to place a Jpanel into another Jpanel but I am having issue in positioning to a desire location(i.e. in the center of Jpanel) which doesn't allow me to align components on a frame. I want something similar to the accepted answer given in the following link [Setting panel at center of screen by using layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411197/setting-panel-at-center-of-screen-by-using-layout/35104089?noredirect=1#comment57929327_35104089)
but this answer is the case where parent panel doesn't have any component where as I have few textfields and labels on my parent panel.

Answer (score 3):

> but this answer is the case where parent panel doesn't have any component where as I have few textfields and labels on my parent panel.

So then in you main panel you would probably use a BorderLayout.

In the `PAGE_START` location (ie, the NORTH) you would create a panel with your text fields and labels and.

Then you create another panel that just uses the GridBagLayout and add this panel to the "CENTER" of the BorderLayout.

Finally, you create your child panel which you can then add to the panel in the CENTER and the child panel will be centered in that space.

The key to layout management is the nesting of panels with different layout managers to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to insert a panel in the center of another Panel, you can use BorderLayout.

I write to you an example:

```
JPanel main = new JPanel();
JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();

main.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
main.add(secondPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(main);
```

Comment: This does not "center" the child panel in the parent panel.

Comment: It doesn't help because I am using grid layout for both panels if I change the layout for parent panel like I tried making it box layout and border layout either it does not display anything or it gives an error. therefore I am using box layout for child panel and it works but displays the components of child panel at one side of a form whereas I am trying to display them in a middle of a parent panel. So child panel has some of the text fields and labels above and a button of a parent panel below it