# Add JComponents in the middle of the JPanel

Tags: java, swing, vertical-alignment, layout-manager

I would like to have a trade-off between FlowLayout and GridBagLayout. In a nutshell, I've some components to add in my JPanel (I don't know how many of these, it's a creation at runtime) and I would like that these components to be center vertically.
FlowLayout was ideal for my goal, but it adds components at the top of JPanel. So, I decided to use GridBagConstraints, as someone suggested here ([Java layout manager vertical center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897924/java-layout-manager-vertical-center)) but my problem with this solution is that GridBagLayout doesn't create a new line automatically, so I've just one row (vertically center, at least!!!) where my components are inserted that goes beyond the screen size. Could anyone give me some tricks about that???

Comment: you can use GridBagLayout to add new rows so to speak simply by specifying the correct x and y coordinates in your constraints. Each time you increase y, you're in effect putting the next component on a new row.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like that these components to be center vertically. FlowLayout was ideal for my goal, but it adds components at the top of JPanel

You are never forced to use a single panel or layout manager. You can use nested panels. For example:

```
JPanel centered = new JPanel( choose your layout manager );

Box vertical = Box.createVerticalBox();
vertical.add( Box.createVerticalGlue() );
vertical.add( centered );
vertical.add( Box.createVerticalGlue() );
frame.add( vertical );
```

The glue in the vertical panel will take up equal amounts of extra space which leaves the "centered" panel vertically centered. So you can add components to the centered panel using whatever layout you want.