# Java: How to set up a grid for sudoku solver using Swing and super.paintChildren(g)

Tags: java, swing, paint, sudoku

i have to do a sudoku solver with a gui for school. The gui is almost done, i just need to draw a grid for the sudoku board.
I have implemented the sudoku board with the GridLayout (9x9 JTextFields) but i am not allowed to draw the borders directly within this method.

For the grid i have to use an own method:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

        super.paintChildren(g);
}
```

I have drawn a grid already:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public final class Field extends JPanel {
    
    private JPanel sudokuPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel sudokuBox = new JPanel();


    /**
     * 9x9 Sudoku grid.
     */

    public Sudoku() {
              
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension(400, 380));
        
        sudokuPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        
        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                sudokuBox = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
                
                for (int cell = 0; cell < 9; cell++) {
                    sudokuBox.add(new JTextField());
                }

                sudokuPanel.add(sudokuBox);
                add(sudokuPanel);
                setVisible(true);
                setBorder(null);
                
            }
            
        }

    } 
    

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        super.paintChildren(g);
   
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        
        for ( int x = 0; x < 360 ; x += 40 ) {
            for ( int y = 0; y < 360; y += 40 ) {
                graphics.drawRect( x, y, 40, 40 ); 
            }
        }
        
    }
```

The Layout of the JTextFields (sudokuBox), is set up in an own class.

Requirements: The sudokuPanel has to stay centred in my JFrame and does not have to scale, when i resize the Window manually on my Desktop (I use an BorderLayout for that and that just works fine).

The Problem is, that my Grid stays in the upper left corner of my Window. It does not move, when i make the Window smaller and bigger. How do i make, that the drawn grid lays over my sudokuPanel, even, when i am resize the Window of the Application?

[SudokuGUI - Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c1SO.jpg)

Thanks for every hint!

Comment: This: `public void paint(Graphics graphics) {

        super.paintChildren(graphics);
}` is not good. You should never be doing this in fact

Comment: Thank you! But i am not allowed to change this. I have to use this to complete the Task. :/

Comment: I think using a JTable would make more sense than adding 9 JTextFields

Comment: Oh nice idea, never thought of that! Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

To center the grid both vertically and horizontally just create a `JPanel` with `GridBagLayout` and add to it a single `Component` (the grid). This can be seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/898054).

For example, to make a centered grid of 9x9 `JTextField`s with black lines, you can:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class MainWithTextFields {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        final Border fieldBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
        
        final JPanel grid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(9, 0));
        for (int i = 0; i < 81; ++i) {
            final JTextField field = new JTextField(2);
            field.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER); //Center text horizontally in the text field.
            field.setBorder(fieldBorder); //Add the colored border.
            grid.add(field);
        }
        
        final JPanel centeredGrid = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        centeredGrid.add(grid);
        
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sudoku");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(centeredGrid);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(MainWithTextFields::createAndShowGUI);
    }
}
```

Or, to make a centered grid of 9x9 `JTable` cells, you can:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainWithTable {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        final JPanel grid = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        grid.add(new JTable(9, 9), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        final JPanel centeredGrid = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        centeredGrid.add(grid);
        
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sudoku");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(centeredGrid);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(MainWithTable::createAndShowGUI);
    }
}
```

Now resizing the frame, won't resize the contents, but instead make them go to the center of it.

You also don't need to override `paintComponent` at all in those cases. If it is a requirement to override it in order to paint the borders of the `JTextField`s, just create the `GridLayout` setting the horizontal and the vertical gap to be for example 3 pixels, and the middle pixels draw them with black lines.